# Run two scripts in a node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, process

I am trying to run two executables in a node.js "scripts" section. One of them is a node.js executable (let's call it `proc1`) , and the other is `http-server` for serving some static assets. These are both process that run continuously. I'd like a way to manage these together, so that they start together, and can both be stopped together. I also want to be able to see the output of the `cosmos` command.

I tried configuring it like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "http-server >> /dev/null &; proc1",
}
```

But this gives out the error:

> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;' 
>   sh: -c: line 0:`http-server &; proc1'

I tried to find a simple node.js process management solution to run this alongside, but couldn't find an appropriate one (similar to `supervisor` in the Python world).

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

create just another node.js script to that starts/stops both of ur servers.

Answer (score 0):

> sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;' 
>   sh: -c: line 0:`http-server &; proc1'

The error is in your shell code.  Change it to

```
"http-server >> /dev/null & proc1",
```

You can't end a statement with `&`, to run in the background, and also end it with `;`.

Comment: This is great, but the problem is when I hit Ctrl-C to kill `proc`, the http-server keeps running in the background. Is there a way to kill that as well?

Comment: It was backgrounded, so it did not receive the SIGINT sent to the foreground process when you typed Ctrl-C. You'll have to find the process and send it a signal. Your shell's job control may help, if the shell ran the process but if it was spawned by something else (maybe nodejs?) then it may have been reparented to init and you'll have to find it in the process list.